# has_many through query not returning expected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models User, Company and Privilege and the relationships are as follows

user.rb

```
has_many :privileges
has_many :companies, through: :privileges
```

company.rb

```
has_many :privileges
has_many :users, through: :privileges
```

privilege.rb

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :user
```

Now I want companies for a user with all the privileges

I tried some solutions from stackoverflow and documentation but I am not able to get desired results

```
user = User.find(1)
user.companies.includes(:privileges).references(:privileges)
```

but this does not return the privileges which is something I really want for further processing

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Without knowing what your expected result is, I think what you are looking for is: `User.includes(companies: :privileges)`

Comment: I want companies for a user with all privileges

Comment: It's a difficult thing to do with pure rails. I would manually build the query using a scope on a user. Something like: `User.with_all_privileges`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `includes(:privileges)` as `has_many :through` generates inner join

If you need privileges you need to request them. I think this request will give you what you expected:

```
Privilege.where(user_id: user.id)
```

If you need to check that company id is present too:

```
Privilege.where(user_id: user.id).where.not(company_id: nil)
```